# Show that $A$ is connected given that $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$ are connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Can anyone help in proving this statement. I have thought and tried but can't seem to do it.

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space and let $A$, $B$ be two closed subsets of $X$.
If $A\cup B$ & $A\cap B$ are connected, then show that $A$ is also connected.

Comment: Use "\cup" for $\cup$ and "\cap" for $\cap$.

Comment: Also, what have you thought and tried?

Comment: Proof by the function characterisation of connectedness: Suppose $f:A \to \{0,1\}$ is continuous (the latter space discrete), $f$ is constant on $A \cap B$ as that set is connected. Extend $f$ to $A \cup B$ by using that same constant on $B$ too (glueing lemma, uses the two sets are closed (or open)). The extension is constant on $A \cup B$ by *its* connectedness, so $f$ was already constant on $A$ to begin with. Hence $A$ is connected.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't think that works. What if $A\cap B = \emptyset$? $\emptyset$ is also connected.
**Update**: On second thoughts, the intersection can't be empty.